# 7-zip (7za.EXE) in C# to archive files of same name & store folder information

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0, 7zip

My software is supposed to collect files into a .zip or .7z archive using 7zip, but due to the nature of the software, there are a lot of files with the same name, but different directories like:

```
D:\Software\Components\Station1\Alarms\Logs\ValvePressureSensor.xml
D:\Software\Components\Station1\Configurations\ValvePressureSensor.xml
D:\Software\Components\Station2\Alarms\Logs\ValvePressureSensor.xml
```

These files are stored in a list "FileList.lst" and I am calling 7-zip this way:

```
7za a -t7z "D:\Software\CollectedData\Diagnostics.7z" 
"@D:\Software\ZipTemp\FileList.lst"
```

So I'm wondering whether there is a way to keep the directories of each file when they are zipped to stop 7-zip from flagging duplicate files?

I am aware of the workaround involving the removal of "D:\" from the beginning of each file path, but this would be impossible manually as the "FileList.lst" is populated in the C# code with around 1500~3000 files (which aren't always the same files), and the FileList.lst is located in a temporary folder which is created, zipped, then destroyed dynamically. So I couldn't store the 7za.EXE in the same area. On top of that, the file list is used by another executable which does need the drives specified in the file paths.

I should mention that I am using Visual Studio 2005, C#2.0, and 7-zip v9.20.

EDIT: my question was fairly broad before, I should clarify that I'm switching from WinZip(due to licensing issues) so I recall that in WinZip  If you add -p switch, WinZip will store folder information for all files added, not just for files from subfolders; the folder information will begin with the folder specified on the command line.   Do you know of something similar in 7zip?

EDIT 2: turns out you cannot keep file folder info with 7-zip

Comment: Question on usage of `7za.exe` would be more appropriate for SuperUser.

Comment: Why not use C# to create the zip-file instead of using 7zip? There are several libraries like DotNetZip or SharpZipLib (or if you had been using .net 3.0 and up, System.IO.Packaging and System.IO.Compression).

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren or a C# wrapper around 7z.dll http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/

Comment: @kenny see EDIT, is this possible with just vanilla 7-zip or would sevenzipsharp allow this?

Comment: @DarthSheldon, sorry I don't know. I had a similar path issue that I had to work around. I don't think the C# wrapper adds any functionality that you can get at via the command line.

Comment: @kenny you wouldn't have any info/solutions handy for working around that path issue would you?

Comment: as I remember, fallible, I changed the working directory to the base and zipped up the files from a directory. Doing one file at a time, I was not able to keep the path in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am aware of the workaround involving the removal of "D:\" from the beginning of each file path, but this would be impossible manually

So remove it dynamically. If your paths are consistent, a simple `path.Substring(3)` will suffice.

Comment: On top of that, the file list is used by another executable which does need the drives specified in the file paths.

Comment: @DarthSheldon: Is having two files a problem?

Comment: curious how I would implement this? as of now I have foreach (FileInfoWrapper wrapper in files)
                    {
                        incrementZipStatusBar();
                        FileInfo item = wrapper.Info as FileInfo;
                        includedFiles.Add(item.FullName.ToLower(), null);  where item would represent the file path and includedFiles adds the file into the FileList.lst

Comment: also Path doesn't contain a .Substring() as far as I can see

Comment: sorry I forgot to direct these to you

Comment: @DarthSheldon: `item.FullName.Substring(3).ToLower()`, in that case, should work just fine.

Comment: sweet I'll check that out. otherwise> string X = item.DirectoryName.ToString(); X.TrimStart('D:\\');